# C LinkedList won't work

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to construct my own LinkedList in C for several hours now, and I am just unable to make it work properly. Please point out where and why this code goes wrong. For the actual behaviour scroll down to 'main'.

```
struct List {
  struct Node * head;
} list;

struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node * next;
} node;

void
add(struct List* list, int z){

  //add as first element
  if(list -> head == NULL){
    list -> head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    (list -> head) -> data = z;
    (list -> head) -> next = NULL;
    return;
  }

  //add to tail
  struct Node * curr = list -> head;

  while((curr -> next) != NULL){
    curr = curr -> next;
  }

  list -> head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  (list -> head) -> data = z;
  (list -> head) -> next = NULL;
  return; 
}

void
printNode(struct Node * node){

  if(node == NULL){
    printf("NULL\n");
    return;
  }

  printf("%d -> ", node->data);
  printNode(node->next);

}

void
printList(struct List * list){
  if(list->head == NULL)
    printf("empty\n");
  else
    printNode(list->head);
}
```

For some reason it appears that 'add' does alter the passed List in a way such that only the last element remains in there. I've re-written the program several times - recursive and iterative - and the result always seems to be this.

```
int
main(){

  struct List myList;
  myList.head = NULL;

  printList(&myList); // empty  
  add(&myList, 1);
  printList(&myList); // 1 -> NULL
  add(&myList, 2);
  printList(&myList); // 2 -> NULL, should be 1 -> 2 -> NULL
  add(&myList, 3);
  printList(&myList); // 3 -> NULL, should be 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL
  add(&myList, 4);
  printList(&myList); // 4 -> NULL, should be 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL
}
```

I've even recreated the program in other languages to see if there was any groundbreaking logical flaw in the procedures, but elsewhere I got it to work right away.

Comment: Just take a piece of paper, write columns for every variable in `add()`, and then write rows for each line of code in `add()`.  What is the value of each variable at each step.  You will see soon enough.

Comment: The johannes' reply is correct, but your program is also terribly inefficient.  You should either add new element to the beginning of the list, or store the pointer to the last node in the List structure.  That is the whole point of lists.

Comment: Debugger..........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program you're searching for the last element:

```
while((curr -> next) != NULL){
  curr = curr -> next;
}
```

this s correct, but then you're changing the head:

```
list -> head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
(list -> head) -> data = z;
(list -> head) -> next = NULL;
```

Instead you should create a new element and change the `next` pointer of the current end:

```
struct Node *new_data = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
new_node -> data = z;
new_node -> next = NULL;
curr -> next = new_node;
```

Comment: Oh well, you are of course absolutely correct. Now I'm feeling *very* dumb for not finding that error..

Answer (score 1):

it kind of looks like you need to decide if you are going to add to the head or the tail... it looks like you are kind of trying to add to the head, but then you would make next current rather than null...

```
list -> head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
(list -> head) -> data = z;
(list -> head) -> next = NULL; // HERE <-- next is NULL
```

rather than:

```
list -> head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
(list -> head) -> data = z;
(list -> head) -> next = curr;
```